# Boost serial communication, COM port is denied with error "open: access is denied"

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port

I have a simple program, the Boost library, built and linked etc.

When I run the code below, I get an error saying " open: access is denied". I get that is may well mean the port is already open and therefore not available. however, I can access the COM port very easily in both C# and another C++ program, however I have no idea how implement that in Boost and my search hasn't been very productive.

```
void main()
{
try 
{       
    SerialSimple ss("COM12", 115200);       
    //ss.writeString("hi");
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    cout << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << endl;
}

_getch();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: What's a SerialSimple? If thats your code please show, it, or link to the specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you are attempting to open the same port for each read without closing it in a separate instance (either C# or this program).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by disconnecting connection and then starting it again - am using Tera Term. Even though I have no idea how, it must have been opened by something else when I was attempting to write to it.